# How to stop poly objects spawning into each other when randomizing their location MAYA

Tags: python, random, collision-detection, maya

Hi im working on a script were i spawn random instances of polycubes on the Maya grid. However I don't how to stop these cubes spawning on top of each or inside of each other. I have heard the word bounding box been thrown around on the internet but im not sure how to make one. Can someone help me I've been working on this for days. (Im coding in Python)

Answer (score 1):

If you save the location of each cube as a tuple() you can keep those in a set.  Then just check the set every time you roll the dice for a new location to and re-roll if that combination has already been used:

```
import random
already_seen = set()
created = []
while len(created) < 11:
    x = random.randint(-10, 10)
    y = random.randint(-10,10)
    z = random.randint(-10,10)
    pos = (x, y, z)
    if pos not in already_seen:
       already_seen.add(pos)
       node, shape = cmds.polyCube()
       cmds.xform(node, t = pos)
       created.append(node)
```

This uses integer positions because that gets you off the hook for distance checking each new point against all previous ones. You could treat the integer positions as a 'cell' and add a smaller random offset inside that cell keep it less rigid if that matters.